# How would I generate a random and unique title in cpp

Tags: c++

im kind of new to cpp coding. Anyway I was wondering how I would add random and unique titles to my program that change every time I open it, EG: If i sent a friend a file it might be called **2377213** the first time he opens it but then second time: **234h234j23bg43v202**

So it's randomized 
Would it be possible to do with this and if so how?

`SetConsoleTitleA();`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: How much randomness are we talking about?

Comment: uh doesnt need to be many

Comment: It seems like you want to generate a random sequence of bits of a Gaussian length and encode them as Base64, or approximately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the console title you can simply write

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    srand(time(nullptr));//changes random seed
    string title="";
    int n=10;//title length
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a=rand()%2; //50% numbers and 50% letters
        if(a==0)
            title+=rand()%26+'a';//generates letters
        else
            title+=to_string(rand()%10);//generates numbers
    }
    SetConsoleTitleA(title.c_str());
    cout<<"test"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry for asking but where would the title+=rand()%26+'a'; go?

Comment: You can put  title+=rand()%26+'a' in the for loop to add the letters to the title. You can also random generate a number "0 or 1" to decide if put a number or a letter: You generate a "0 or 1" with "int a=rand()%2;" and you can check with an if "if(a==0)" you use the "title+=to_string(rand()%10);" to generate a number, "else" you use "title+=rand()%26+'a'" to generate a letter

Comment: alright that worked but now when im doing SetConsoleTitleA(title()); im just getting an error

Comment: Can you write the error? However I recommend to use "system()" on windows

Comment: `rand` is, like, sooooo 1970s. Can I talk you into using [the `<random>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)?

Comment: First check if you have included "windows.h".If you have the string "title" you have to call the function in that way: "SetConsoleTitleA(title.c_str())"; The c_str() convertes the string in a char array[Documentation][http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/]

Comment: Alright thank you, no errors now but the title is just the project name :)

Comment: *convert the string in a char array* Probably no conversion required. Modern C++ `string` implementations are pretty much forced to hold the string as a `char` array because `c_str()` is required to have a O(1) time complexity.

Comment: @Spacey You mean that only the console name changed?

Comment: While collision is unlikely, this answer cannot guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: If one wanted to have letters and numbers, (or anything else,) you could have a static character set of all the characters, and then index into it by a random amount.

Comment: @DomenicoLanza Nothing changed at all, this gives no errors but did noting ```SetConsoleTitleA(title.c_str());```

Comment: Try to print the title string to make sure it's ok

Comment: it works but wont run anything below it for some reason
https://imgur.com/a/nRCsKoc

Comment: Your code should be like this `#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    string title="";
    int n=10;//title length
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            title+=rand()%26+'a';
    }
    SetConsoleTitleA(title.c_str());
    cout<<"test"<<endl;

    return 0;
}

`

Comment: My bad, i got it working now, it was another function stopping it from working properly :) thank you

Comment: One last question what would be the code for like 4er24532rfesd
So just mixed Number & Letter

Comment: I've put the code in the answer for 50% numbers and 50% letters

Comment: Alright, thank you! :)

Comment: @Spacey If you have done can you accept my answer? :)

Comment: Done :) and thank you again

Comment: Combination of what @Neil and I are talking about: https://ideone.com/Z48MSn